# Using sed in echo command for bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sed

I would like to extract the last line of the log in BackupPC, so if a failed backup occurs, I will know why by the email. I have used the command`sed` to get the last line of the log. However, I'm having difficulties echoing that out to the screen. It's showing the FAILED line, but not the error line from the log. How can I fix this, and/or is there a better way to do this?

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to send simple email
# Email To ?
EMAIL="myemail@mydomain.com"
# Email text/message
EMAILMESSAGE="/var/lib/backuppc/emailmessage.txt"
#Extract the last line of the log for error reporting
LOG_FILE="/var/lib/backuppc/log/LOG" 
#Grab the status variables
xferOK=$1
host=$2
type=$3
client=$4
hostIP=$5
share=$6
XferMethod=$7
sshPath=$8
cmdType=$9

# Check if backup succeeded or not.
if [[ $xferOK == 1 ]]; then
        STATUS="has been SUCCESSFUL"

# Email text/message
echo "$client backup $STATUS" > $EMAILMESSAGE
echo "------------------------------------------------------" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Type: $type" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Client: $client" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Host: $host" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Host IP: $hostIP" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Share: $share" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "XferMethod: $XferMethod" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "sshPath: $sshPath" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "cmdType: $cmdType" >>$EMAILMESSAGE

/usr/sbin/sendmail "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE


else
        STATUS="has FAILED"


#If it had failed, send out the error report
# Email text/message
echo "$client backup $STATUS" > $EMAILMESSAGE
echo "---------------------------------" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "$LOG_FILE" | sed -n '$p' >>$EMAILMESSAGE

/usr/sbin/sendmail "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
```

The output from my emails. No line from the LOG file whatsoever.

```
ukat2 backup has FAILED
---------------------------------
```

Comment: *However, I'm having difficulties* - what difficulties?

Comment: You mean `echo "$EMAILMESSAGE"`?

Comment: `tail -n1 "${LOG_FILE}" >> "${EMAILMESSAGE}"`?

Comment: Off-topic: That script could benefit from using a here-document to create the message.

Answer (score 1):

`echo "$LOG_FILE" | sed -n '$p'` does not extract the last line of the file `$LOG_FILE`, it takes the last line of what is sent to its standard input, that is your log file name (`/var/lib/backuppc/log/LOG`) which should appear in your e-mail.

The correct syntax would be:

```
sed -n '$p' "$LOG_FILE"
```

Or, better, since showing the N last lines is the job of `tail`:

```
tail -n 1 "$LOG_FILE"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the correct syntax is....echo tail -n 1 "$LOG_FILE" >>$EMAILMESSAGE ?

Comment: @Marc, exactly.

Comment: Just ran the script, and I got: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `tail' and line 34: `echo (tail -n 1 $LOG_FILE) >>$EMAILMESSAGE'. Any ideas?

Comment: That's `tail -n 1 "$LOG_FILE" >>$EMAILMESSAGE`, no `echo` (sorry, didn't spot it) and no parentheses

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it helped. Then you may want to accept the answer :)